# access multiple my sql database at a time?

Tags: sql

how can i access multiple my sql database at time, what is the mechanism behind it?????
   eg: i have three different database that contain product(shoes) along with price and there description etc...
   so whenever the user type shoes and set its price ... my search bar should be able to retrieve the data in respect of price.. from multiple database..

Comment: Do you mean MySQL databases?

Comment: Accessing multiple database is symmetrically the same as accessing one, once you know how to access one database, you can expand the idea to as many as you need - or do you mean tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like

```
Select * FROM database1.products WHERE field = ?
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM database2.products  field = ?
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM database3.products field = ?
```

Comment: OP is talking about multiple databases. Not multiple tables.